# Show that if $f$ is uniformly continuous and if $|p_n-q_n|\to 0$, then $|f(p_n)-f(q_n)|\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $D$, show that it has the property that if $p_n,q_n\in D$ and $|p_n-q_n|\to 0$, then $|f(p_n)-f(q_n)|\to 0$.

This question is a suggested problem from my professor but I couldn't do it. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for each $\epsilon>0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that for every $p_n,q_n\in D$ , $|p_n-q_n|<\delta$ implies $|f(p_n)-f(q_n)|<\epsilon$. We need to show as $\delta \to 0$, we have $\epsilon \to 0$. But can we change our delta randomly for the same epsilon? I'm confused at this point because delta is dependent to epsilon. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Always first **fix** $\epsilon$ before finding $\delta$

Comment: But we need to show $\epsilon \to 0$, should we write delta dependent to epsilon?

Comment: @Burak That's the idea, find a suitable dependence of $\delta$ on $\epsilon$. You seem to be missing something when you write "We need to show as $\delta\to0$, we have $\epsilon\to0$."

Comment: Is it apt if I choose $\epsilon=|p_n-q_n|$, because $p_n,q_n$ are different elements. Uniform continuty restricts us to choose delta independent from the chosen elements, but not on the epsilon. Or does it? And I couldn't find that suitable delta which depends on epsilon. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$f $ is uniformly continuous at $D $

thus

$$ \exists \eta>0 \;  :  \;\forall x,y\in D $$

$$|x-y|<\eta\implies |f (x)-f (y)|<\epsilon $$

on the other hand

$$\exists N\in\mathbb N :$$
$$n>N \implies |p_n-q_n|<\eta $$

thus

$$n>N\implies |f (p_n)-f (q_n)|<\epsilon $$

which means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f (p_n)-f (q_n))=0.$$

Comment: Does $\eta$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @Burak, That need not be the case. (For instance, if $f$ is a constant function, then you can pick $\eta = 2017$ for any choice of $\epsilon$.) But the point is that you need not worry about this.

Comment: I don't understand the last line. How did we arrive to $\lim_{n\to\infty}(f (p_n)-f (q_n))=0$?

Comment: @Burak, That's because the definition of the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ is $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \ \exists N \in \Bbb{N} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad n > N \ \Rightarrow \ |a_n - L| < \epsilon. $$ The last line is a particular case when $a_n = f(p_n) - f(q_n)$ and $L = 0$.

Comment: Wow, I see it now. Thanks both of you.